# Django Query group_by datetime contains duplicate data of dates

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

Hi I've been trying to debug what's wrong with my Django query but I still couldn't figure it out. I have a model called 'Ticket', and it has a field called 'created', which is a datetime field. I am trying return an array of objects containing the count of tickets created for each unique day (yyyy-mm-dd) within a given date range (from and to), but I get 1 duplicate date which is weird. Please see results below and my code. The date "2021-02-08" has 1 duplicate while others are all correct. When I checked the database the count for "2021-02-08" really has more than 20 rows, I assume the datetime being saved isn't timezone aware. I have also configured the timezone of my Django project set to be 'Asia/Manila'. I am also inheriting TimeStampedModel for the Ticket model which automatically populates 'created' and 'modified' field. (https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html)

Data returned in JSON:

```
"activation_chart_data": [
    {
        "date": "2021-02-08",
        "count": 20
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-02-08",
        "count": 31
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-02-09",
        "count": 32
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-02-11",
        "count": 15
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-02-12",
        "count": 51
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-02-15",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-02-16",
        "count": 4
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-02-18",
        "count": 15
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-02-23",
        "count": 5
    }
]
```

Django Query:

```
Ticket.objects.filter(Q(created__gte=from_date) & Q(
            created__lte=end_date) & Q(type__slug='activation-code')).extra(select={'date': 'date(shop_ticket.created)'}).order_by('created__date').values('date').annotate(count=Count('created'))
```

Raw Postgre SQL Query being executed:

```
SELECT (date(shop_ticket.created)) AS "date", COUNT("shop_ticket"."created") AS "count" FROM "shop_ticket" INNER JOIN "shop_tickettype" ON ("shop_ticket"."type_id" = "shop_tickettype"."id") WHERE ("shop_ticket"."created" >= 2021-03-01 00:00:00+08:00 AND "shop_ticket"."created" <= 2021-03-09 00:00:00+08:00 AND "shop_tickettype"."slug" = activation-code) GROUP BY (date(shop_ticket.created)), ("shop_ticket"."created" AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Manila')::date ORDER BY ("shop_ticket"."created" AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Manila')::date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `distinct=true` in Count

```
Ticket.objects.filter(
    Q(created__gte=from_date) &
    Q(created__lte=end_date) &
    Q(type__slug='activation-code')
).extra(
    select={'date': 'date(shop_ticket.created)'}
).order_by('created__date').values('date').annotate(
    count=Count('created', distinct=True)
)
```